# Flowfile absolute path Nifi

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, bulk-load

I'm trying to load the flow files into MySQL database using bulk load option. Below is the query I'm using as part of the **UpdateAttribute** processor and passing that query to **PutSQL** after updating the parameters to do bulk load.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '${absolute.path}${filename}' INTO TABLE ${dest.database}.${db.table.name} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

When I ran the flow it's failing saying file not found exception.

```
. There were a total of 1 FlowFiles that failed, 0 that succeeded, and 0 that were not execute and will be routed to retry; : java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Unable to open file 'data.csv'for 'LOAD DATA INFILE command.Due to underlying IOException:`

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.FileNotFoundException
MESSAGE: data.csv (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.csv (No such file or directory).
```

Here MySQL Server and Nifi are on different nodes so I can't use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query.

I'm not sure why I'm getting file not found exception even though I mentioned the complete absolute path of the flow file in the SQL Query.

When I use query with hard coded file name and providing the absolute path of the file in nifi node, it's working as expected.

**Working:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/in/nifi/node/to/file/data.csv' INTO TABLE ${dest.database}.${db.table.name} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'}
```

Question is how to get the absolute path of the flow file and load the same flow file into mysql.

**Flow:**

[image]

Comment: as i know, the flowfile is not present on disk as a plain file. even if you'll get the path to storage on disk, it could contain several flow files or part of one flow file. so, you have to use PutFile to store flowfile to a desired path, and then call LOAD DATA LOCAL... command with the same path.

Comment: @daggett, I tried that approach suggested by you, it working as expected, however writing the flowfile to disk seems to be a costly operation. As I have huge number of flowfiles and each flowfile is bigger in size it's hitting performance a lot.

Comment: what if you split csv file by smaller sizes(for example 100k) and configure sequence so, that while PutFile stores physical file, the another part is executing with LOAD DATA LOCAL ?

Comment: @daggett, if the split size 100k records, as there are billions of records in the table, I might get huge number of flow files and writing those flow files to disk will be costly operation.

Answer (score 0):

- Stop the `PutSQL` processor and let the flowfiles queue up.
- Once they are queued up, right click on the `success` relationship
  between `UpdateAttribute` and `PutSQL` and select `List Queue`.
- Select any one flowfile and navigate to the `Attributes` tab and see 
  if the attributes `absolute.path` and `flowfilename` exists and if
  they do exist, verify if they have the expected value set. In your case `absolute.path` should have the value `/path/in/nifi/node/to/file` and `flowfilename` should have the value `/data.csv`

Question for you: Are you setting these attributes yourself using `UpdateAttribute`, reason is, NiFi doesn't generate an attribute named `flowfilename`, it generates one with the name `filename`.

One more thing, make sure either the value for `absolute.path` ends with a `/` in the end or the value of `flowfilename` begins with a `/`. If not, they will be appended and the result will be `/path/in/nifi/node/to/filedata.csv`. You can try the `append` function that @Mahendra suggested, else you can simply use `${absolute.path}/${flowfilename}`.

**Update**

I just realized that `absolute.path` is a core attribute like `filename`, `filesize`, `mime.type`, etc. Some processors use all the core attributes while some use very few which are needed. `GenerateTableFetch` writes `absolute.path` but doesn't set anything for it. That's why it has `./` which is the default value.

So my suggestion for your approach to work is, you can manually set/overwrite `absolute.path` attribute using `UpdateAttribute` (just like you have overwritten `filename`) and set the desired value which is `/path/in/nifi/node/to/file`

Comment: For readability purpose I gave name as flowfilename, however Nifi is generating filename and in my query also I'm using filename. File name attribute have value data.csv and absolute.path attribute has value ./ and when I'm using ${absolute.path}/${filename} or ${absolute.path}${filename}, I'm getting filenotfound error.

Comment: Let me get one thing clear: this `absolute.path` is manually created by you using `UpdateAttribute`? Or is it being generated by some NiFi file based processors and you are trying to use that ? It would also help, if you can export the flow and share it here.

Comment: Nifi is generating the path attribute(value is / ) and when I use ${absolute.path} in my query and when I check the Nifi attributes i${absolute.path} value it's showing as ./

Comment: Which processor is generating that attribute?

Comment: Generatetable fetch is the processor generating the SQL statements for Execute SQL and in that processor path is getting generated.

Comment: I highly doubt that. `GenerateTableFetch` doesn't write that attribute. Path specific attributes are usually written by file based processors. Also please check https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch/index.html You can see `absolute.path` is not present in the list of attributes this processors write.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167249/discussion-between-user805-and-de-santa).